# How to make an supplied environment run Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

I have been given an conda environment to use ("environ.yml")  that I want to use with Python 2.7.

I have both Anaconda 2 and 3 installed.  Whenever I use the cmd tool to create a new environment it always is created in the Anaconda3 folder so I guess it is using Python 3, which isn't what I want.

How can I use this supplied environment with Anaconda 2?

Comment: There is no matter Anaconda2 or Anaconda3 you are using, it is just the python version of your anaconda but not your environment's. To create a python2.7 environment. `conda create -n what_ever_you_want python=2.7`

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to open the python3 environment list all modules installed using:

```
conda list
```

Then create a new environment in python2.7 that has all the modules mentioned.

```
conda create --name environ2 python=2.7 anaconda
```

Then run `conda install module_name` for each module in the list

I don't believe you can change only the version of the environment (some module version numbers won't be available across python distributions, some modules won't be available at all!)